# VueJS custom v-model without value property - this shouldn't work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Based on my understanding of using v-model on a custom component (docs link below) the custom component should either:

1. Have a property on the data object of "value" since by default v-model is really 'v-bind:value="valuePassed"'
2. Have a "model" property on the component instance to specify which property to use.

Therefore, why does this fiddle work?
https://jsfiddle.net/mpctwfaq/2/

EDIT: This fiddle seems to work on Firefox but not Chrome at the moment...

parent:

```
<custom-select v-bind:options="formOptions" v-model="formOptionsVModel">
```

child:

```
this.$emit("input", this.customArraySelectedOptions)
```

Specifically, I emit the input event to the parent component with the name of a custom property "customArraySelectedOptions". However, I AM able to update the child component from the parent method by resetting the parent's "formOptionsVModel" property.

I would think based on the documentation the "downward" update should fail since the child's component property is not "value" and does not define a specific property using "model".

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model

Comment: v-model is not really `v-bind:value="valuePassed" ` its a two way binding ....while `v-bind` is one way binding which means it cannot mutate the data

Answer (score 1):

v-model is syntax sugar for =>

```
:value="modelValue" @input="modelValue = $event.target.value"
```

And hence your variable is being updated.